# Eclipse j2me json parsing

Tags: json, eclipse, parsing, java-me

i'm using eclipse pulsar for j2me apps . How to set up **json parsing library** for my project?

i tried to use [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) but not clear about [build with eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/BuildWithEclipse). Is there any other simple solution ?

Comment: Found the solution here .http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Answer (score 1):

Just check [Using JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) in Java ME for Data Interchange](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/) it includes examples how to use it & also you can download [JSON Library for Java ME](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/). Just download json for j2me jar & create library in netbean & add this jar to that library. Now when you want to use this library just right click on resources & add this library.
Thanks

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for eclipse solution not regular. i need to set it up in eclipse pulsar

Comment: In eclipse also same things... You have to create library & add jar jsonme in that. Use that library in your resources.

Comment: No found the solution here http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: http://csm2kh.blogspot.com/2008/05/eclipse-create-users-add-library.html check this link for adding library in Eclipse